# Bug in Intellij 18.1 when I try evaluate expression with var

Tags: java, intellij-idea, method-reference, java-10, intellij-idea-2018

I have this code:

```
import java.util.List;
public class Main {
     public static void main(String[] args) {
          var first = List.of("a", "b", "c").stream().map(String::length).findFirst();
          System.out.print(first);
     }
}
```

When I run normally, this work very well, but when I run with debug and evaluate the expression:

```
List.of("a", "b", "c").stream().map(String::length).findFirst();
```

I receives the message "Method reference evaluation is not supported".

When I run the same code with explicit inference type, the evaluation work normally.

```
import java.util.List;
public class Main {
     public static void main(String[] args) {
          Optional<?> first = List.of("a", "b", "c").stream().map(String::length).findFirst();
          System.out.print(first);
     }
}
```

This is a bug or exists some configuration?

Comment: Could be a bug if works in Run mode. Try to follow the error and see what's going on. evaluation.error.method.reference.evaluation.not.supported=Method reference evaluation is not supported => DebuggerBundle.properties

Comment: Please report a bug https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issues/idea

Comment: https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-189357

Comment: This message appears when you run in debug mode, stop at a breakpoint and change your code in a way that it won't compile anymore. Even when you attempt to evaluate a valid expression now, the compiling process fails so Intellij thinks your expression is the reason for it.

Comment: to close this thread, the issue reported seems to be fixed with intelliJ version `2020.3`